# Sending SSH key into docker using env variables not working

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile, ssh-keys

Am trying to install some private gems(bitbucket git repo) in my docker file and the SSH permission is being denied

What I did was:

1. set my private key to "ssh_key" env variable
2. set a "ssh_config" env variable as "IdentityFile /.ssh/id_rsa Host  User "
3. In docker-compose:

```
    args:
            ssh_key: ${ssh_key}
            ssh_config: ${ssh_config}
```

4. In Dockerfile:

```
    ARG ssh_key
    ARG ssh_config
    RUN mkdir /.sshRUN echo "${ssh_key}" > /.ssh/id_rsa
    RUN echo "${ssh_config}" > /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    RUN chmod 600 /.ssh/id_rsa
    bundle install
```

I get the error

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But when I comment out the private gems and build the image, ssh into the container, remove the id_rsa file and manually paste the host private key using a text editor and run chmod 600(or just mount my host ~/.ssh dir ), then am able to install the private gems without any error.

I don't know what's exactly causing the error. Is there any simpler way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you run [bundle package](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-package.1.html) on your host before running `docker build`, you will have a local copy of all of the gem files you need to install your application.  Then the [bundle install](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-install.1.html) `--local` option will use the local directory instead of trying to fetch files remotely.  Your Dockerfile can look like in part

```
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock .
COPY vendor/cache vendor/cache
RUN bundle install --frozen --local --system
```

This avoids the rather dangerous dance with ssh keys you're attempting: anyone who has the image can look at its `docker history` or just run the container and easily get your ssh private key out.